# What does it mean when somebody dies by "unknown reason?"

Tags: die2nite

I've seen, as of late, quite a few deaths by unknown reason. What does it mean?

Comment: Screenshot courtesy of [Thomas McDonald](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/821/thomas-mcdonald).

Comment: Woohoo, I'm famous. Upvotes all around!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If someone dies for an unknown reason, it's because they deleted their account.

Comment: Way to ruin the fun.

Answer (score 4):

Likely as Mana said, deleting their account.

On a similar note, being "Shot in the head" means they got banned. XD

Answer (score 0):

Nobody knows!   That's part of the fun!

It probably means they fell down a well or something...

It **actually** is likely because the user deleted their account.